# Project size rapidly increasing in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony2 and it is in development mode .The cpanel disk space usage is increased rapidly.The project size exceeds 8GB already.
But when I compress the project then its size is 250 MB.Even if I delete the cache folder the size is not decreasing much and within few minutes it regains the previous size.Please let me know what should I do.

Comment: Are you sure it's the cache folder that's causing the problem? From the way you've mentioned it could be something else. Are your log files huge?

Comment: is it ok to delete the log file? its 5.65 gb..

Comment: beware it might blast off your computer..

Comment: It's fine to delete but you might want to find out why your log files are so big. It's could be an indication that something is wrong. Or just that you've never cleared the log files before and there is a lot of usage on your site.  Alternatively you could use logrotate but I doubt you'll be able to set that up via cpanel.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I used to delete the cache folder,never thought about deleting the log file. :)

Comment: As @Malachi pointed out, find out what is causing so huge log file. By default, `prod` logs include only `ERROR` and `CRITICAL`. Also, maybe consider doing some log rotation in order to be able to delete old files...